# Approximation of integral of gaussian function over a parallelepiped

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, gaussian-integral, approximate-integration

Given a multi-dimensional gaussian function, defined by
$$f(\boldsymbol{x})=\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{x} \right\}=\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \right\}$$
And an integration region as the form of a $n$-dimensional parallelepiped, defined by
$$\mathcal{D} = \left\{\boldsymbol{l \le Lx\le u}   \right\}$$
with

- the lower triangular matrix $\boldsymbol{L}\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ where all lower elements and diagonal equal to $1$, all upper elements equal to $0$
  $$
  \boldsymbol{L} = \left(
  \begin{matrix}
  1&0&0&\ldots&0\\
  1&1&0&\ldots&0\\
  1&1&1&\ldots&0\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\
  1&1&1&\ldots&1\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
  $$
- the vectors $\boldsymbol{l,u} \in \Bbb R^n$: $\boldsymbol{l} = (l_1,...,l_n)'$ and $\boldsymbol{u} = (u_1,...,u_n)'$

[image: The integration region]

Are there any methods/algorithms that we can use to approximate the integral of $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ over $\mathcal{D}$
$$\int_{\mathcal{D}}f(\boldsymbol{x})d\boldsymbol{x}=\int_{\{\boldsymbol{l \le Lx\le u}   \}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{x} \right\}d\boldsymbol{x}$$
satisfying

- *Fast computation*  (because later I must compute many integrals with different values of $\boldsymbol{l,u}$)
- The *accuracy doesn't need to be high* (absolute error less than $10^{-3}$ is sufficient)

**My attempt**: we may use Monte Carlo simulation to approximate this integral but given the very specific form of the integration region and also the integrand, I hope there may exist a faster numerical method/algorithm/closed-form approximation.

Besides, we notices that the inversion matrix $\boldsymbol{L}^{-1}$ is an upper bi-diagonal matrix
$$
\boldsymbol{L}^{-1} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1&-1&0&\ldots&0\\
0&1&-1&\ldots&0\\
0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&-1\\
0&\ldots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
So, by making a change of variable $\boldsymbol{y = Lx}$, we can transform the integral into $$\int_{\mathcal{D}}f(\boldsymbol{x})d\boldsymbol{x}= \int_{\{\boldsymbol{l' \le y \le u'}\}} \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2} \left(y_n^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (y_i-y_{i+1})^2 \right) \right\} d\boldsymbol{y}$$
with $\mathcal{D}' = \{\boldsymbol{l' \le y \le u'}\}$ is a rectangular region.

I tried to use multivariae Mill ratio but it doesn't work. In fact, multivariae Mill ratio is for the calculation of $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{X \le u})$, not $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{l \le X \le u})$ with $\boldsymbol{X}$ following a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu,\Sigma})$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried to approximate it with Mill's ratio? see, https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/66B/jresv66Bn3p93_A1b.pdf and https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/68B/jresv68Bn1p3_A1b.pdf

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you for the Mill's ratio! I haven't known this method yet. I'll try it.

Comment: I think you will find this useful: STECK "LOWER BOUNDS FOR THE MULTIVARIATE NORMAL MILLS' RATIO" The Annals of Probability, 1979, Vol. 7, No. 3, pp547-551. As far as I can remember once I used this publication a long, long time ago ...

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you very much. This paper is really useful. I'll use it. As the inverse of my $\Sigma$ is a tridiagonal matrix, the bounds must be easy to compute.

Comment: Unluckily, the paper of Steck can't help me. Because it presents the bounds of $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{X} \le \boldsymbol{a})$ and not $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{l}\le \boldsymbol{X} \le \boldsymbol{u})$ which is more difficult. PS: if I apply the result of $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{X} \le \boldsymbol{a})$, I need to decompose $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{l}\le \boldsymbol{X} \le \boldsymbol{u})$  in not less than $2^n$ probabilities of type $\mathbb{P}(\boldsymbol{X} \le \boldsymbol{a})$

Comment: Have you you looked at the jresv66Bn3p93_A1b paper? Savage has both upper and lower exponentially tight bounds for tail events.

Comment: It may be of some help if you could specify whether $\|\boldsymbol u\|\gg1$, $\|\boldsymbol v\|\gg1$ or $\|\boldsymbol u-\boldsymbol v\|\ll1$.

Comment: @Saad Unluckily, $\boldsymbol{l}$ and $\boldsymbol{u}$ can take any value in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Can you exploit the fact that different $l,u$ have overlaps, so that MC can produce the value of several integration regions in parallel? I mean that a single sample contributes to the integral in all parallelepipeds that contain it.